# Compare the data in 2 DataTables that are not identical

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable, ado.net

I need to compare 2 datatables. I'm attempting to compare the data in the tables but the column names and datatypes will not mathc as they are based on 2 different sources. Each datatable will have a column that is the id for the table so finding the associated row across tables will not be a problem. I'm looking for speed overall but I'm afraid I will have to do a column by column by row comparison. Can anyone share an effective method they may have used.

UPDATE: Should also have mentioned. The intent is to have a datatable that contains the data in dt1 that does not match dt2 so it can be bound to a grid for user action.

Comment: What exactly are you comparing and what are you trying to accomplish by comparing?

Comment: Comparing the values of the columns are equal. ie dt1.column[1].Value == dt2.column[1].Value, dt1.column[2].Value == dt2.column[2].Value ect